# Remove time from GMT time format

Tags: javascript, date, utc, gmt

I am getting a date that comes in GMT format, Fri, 18 Oct 2013 11:38:23 GMT. The problem is that the time is messing up the timeline that I am using.

How can I strip out everything except for the actual date?

Comment: `console.log(new Date('Fri, 18 Oct 2013 11:38:23 GMT').toDateString());`

Comment: When I do this the GMT date is `Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 GMT 2015` and when I plug it into the `toDateString()` function I end up with `Sun Jan 11 2015`, a day behind.

Comment: try fiddling with `toLocaleString(params)` a bit and provide it desired formatting parameters.

Comment: why not using string functions like substring to strip out everything except date?

Comment: There are many threads here on SO dealing with this, one such thread is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?lq=1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Like this:

```
var dateString = 'Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 GMT 2015';
dateString = new Date(dateString).toUTCString();
dateString = dateString.split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ');
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: I had to change the slice to 0,3 but worked perfectly!! Thanks

Answer (score 34):

If you want to keep using Date and not String you could do this:

```
var d=new Date(); //your date object
console.log(new Date(d.setHours(0,0,0,0)));
```

-PS, you don't need a new Date object, it's just an example in case you want to log it to the console.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp

Comment: If you work with UTC dates, you should use [setUTCHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) because setHours _sets the hours for a specified date according to local time._

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this workaround :

```
// d being your current date with wrong times
new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate())
```

Comment: Life saver, I wish javascript had a LocalDate like Java, to avoid this kind of workarounds

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), a library that provides many helper functions to validate, manipulate, display and format dates and times in JavaScript.

Using Moment.js lib:

```
var dateString = new Date('Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 GMT 2015');
moment(dateString).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```

Or simplified:

```
moment('Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 GMT 2015').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

Comment: Click this link to know how to write a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: There might be nothing wrong with your code, I don't have much knowledge about `javascript`. I had got your question for review by stack overflow. I had to find out any issue. And I found that your answer only contains the code but does not have any explanation. You should tell the OP(The asker of the question) that "what is causing the problem?", the actual solution, and should explain "how does your solution work?".

Answer (score 2):

Well,

Here is my Solution

```js
let dateString = 'Mon May 25 01:07:00 GMT 2020';
let dateObj = new Date(dateString);

console.log(dateObj.toDateString());
// outputs Mon May 25 2020
```

See its documentation on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString

Answer (score 0):

Just cut it with `substring`:

```
 var str = 'Fri, 18 Oct 2013 11:38:23 GMT';
 str = str.substring(0,tomorrow.toLocaleString().indexOf(':')-3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can just manipulate your string without the use of a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```js
var dateTime = 'Fri, 18 Oct 2013 11:38:23 GMT',
    date = dateTime.split(' ', 4).join(' ');
    
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the date to String:

> String dateString = String.valueOf(date);

Then apply *substring* to the String:

> dateString.substring(4, 11) + dateString.substring(30);

You need to take care as converting date to String will actually change the date format as well.