# JavaScript for getting the previous Monday

Tags: javascript, date

I would like for the previous Monday to appear in the field where a user enters today's date.

**E.g.:** If today's date is entered `29-Jan-16` then the code would make the previous Monday's date to appear instead (which would be `25-Jan-16`).

I have seen some code online:

```
function getPreviousMonday() {
  var date = new Date();
  if (date.getDay() != 0) {
    return new Date().setDate(date.getDate() - 7 - 6);
  } else {
    return new Date().setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDate() - 6);
  }
}
```

However, this is not quite working, why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4156516/3112803

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: get Monday and Sunday of the previous week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681702/javascript-get-monday-and-sunday-of-the-previous-week)

Comment: Or a dup of [get the first day of the week from current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think your math is just a little off, and I tidied your syntax;

```
function getPreviousMonday()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var prevMonday = new Date();
    if(date.getDay() == 0){
        prevMonday.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
    }
    else{
        prevMonday.setDate(date.getDate() - (day-1));
    }

    return prevMonday;
}
```

That way you always get the last Monday that happened (which is 7 days ago if today is Monday)

Comment: This returned a number for me instead of a date

Comment: This returns the time since epoch (i believe), instead instantiate the new date object and then make changes.  Trying to do it fluidly will not produce the result you are expecting. (Which is a Date object, instead you receive an integer back)

Comment: execute `new Date(prevMonday);` it will return date

Comment: date.getDay() returns Sunday for 0, not Monday... I like @Philippe Dubé-Tremblay's answer below.

Answer (score 82):

```
var prevMonday = new Date();
prevMonday.setDate(prevMonday.getDate() - (prevMonday.getDay() + 6) % 7);
```

I am a little late but I like this solution. It's a one liner and not that complicated. Making a function for that seems overkill to me.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe for your nice solution. I've put a wrapping function which accepts a date here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52750444/2012407 for those who are interested

Comment: This works as following: add 6 days to `getDay()` (current day of the week, e.g. Friday=5) and the remainder of the division by the number of a week's days (`(5+6)%7=4`) is subtracted from the current's day number (e.g. `29-4=25`).

Comment: The calculation can be `prevMonday.setDate(prevMonday.getDate() - (prevMonday.getDay() || 7) + 1)`.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Philippe Dubé-Tremblay answer, i wanted to come up with something that lets you target any previous day:

```js
let target = 1 // Monday
let date = new Date()
date.setDate(date.getDate() - ( date.getDay() == target ? 7 : (date.getDay() + (7 - target)) % 7 ))
```

This takes into account the previous Monday if today is also Monday

Comment: My solution gets the current date if we are monday. So if you want the same maths, replacing the hardcoded 6 by (7-target) should do it.
If you want the last monday in that case, I think those maths work : date.setDate(date.getDate() - (date.getDay() + (6 - target) % 7 + 1)

Comment: @Philippe Dubé-Tremblay, nice and simple, however if i try your update, it grabs two weeks ago, instead of this week. Example: if I target 2 (Tuesday) while running this today on a Thursday, your code grabs two Tuesdays ago instead of the Tuesday from the start of this week

Comment: Parenthesis problem I think: date.setDate(date.getDate() - (date.getDay() + 6 - target) % 7 + 1)

Answer (score 3):

Using moment.js:

```
moment().day("Monday").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: If today is Sunday `2020-05-10`, and shouldn't this give `2020-05-11` whereas the expected is, `2020-05-03`

Answer (score 2):

**Thank you @Philippe Dubé-Tremblay for your nice solution (above),**

I will just put here the wrapping function for those who, like me, plan to call this function repeatedly.

```
// Accepts a date as parameter or with no parameter will assume the current date.
const getPreviousMonday = (date = null) => {
  const prevMonday = date && new Date(date.valueOf()) || new Date()
  prevMonday.setDate(prevMonday.getDate() - (prevMonday.getDay() + 6) % 7)
  return prevMonday
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just small feedback: instead of rather us _const prevMonday_ instead of _let_ (just to avoid linters flashing :))

Comment: Thanks for your idea @Braulio, I updated the answer :)

Comment: is it possible to set a specific time ie: Last Monday at 7pm PST?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle demonstrating a few different formats: **https://jsfiddle.net/umefez2j/3/**

```
function getMonday(d) {
  var m_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
  var d = new Date(d);
  var day = d.getDay(),
      diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday

  //Use this one to return this format: Mon Jan 25 2016 09:37:51 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
  //return new Date(d.setDate(diff));

  //Use this one to return this format: Mon, 25 Jan 2016
  //monday=new Date(d.setDate(diff)).toUTCString();
  //monday=monday.split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ')
  //return monday;

  //Use this one to return this format: 25-Jan-2016
  monday=new Date(d.setDate(diff));
  var curr_date = monday.getDate();
  var curr_month = monday.getMonth();
  var curr_year = monday.getFullYear();
  return curr_date + "-" + m_names[curr_month] + "-" + curr_year;
}

alert(getMonday(new Date()));

//Created with help from:
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/27480352/3112803
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/4156516/3112803
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/27869948/3112803
```

Comment: I edited the answer to include a third format and to give props to the source that helped generate this.  Hope this helps.  I see you're new to stackoverflow, if this works for you mark this as the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions **didn't** work for me.

In @Philippe Dubé-Tremblay's solution, it will return the same day if today is already monday!

```
function getPreviousMonday() : Date {
    let date = new Date();
    let day = date.getDay();
    let prevMonday = new Date();
    if(day == 0 || day == 1){
         prevMonday.setDate(date.getDate() - (day + 6));
    }
    else{
        prevMonday.setDate(date.getDate() - (day - 1));
    }
    return prevMonday;
}
```

**OR**

```
 if (day == 1) {
  prevMonday.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
}
else {
  prevMonday.setDate(date.getDate() - (day + 6) % 7);;
}
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to get the last monday from a given date. If the given date is a monday, it returns the same day. This can be used to get the monday of the week that the date is on

```js
let currDate = new Date();
let lastMonday = new Date();
let daysDiff = currDate.getDay() - 1;
lastMonday.setDate(currDate.getDate() - (daysDiff > 0 ? daysDiff : (daysDiff * -6)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//function to find the last monday from a given date
function getPreviousMonday(dateObj){
    // get the year, month and week day from the given date.
    var dayOfWeek = dateObj.getDay();
    var dateObjYear = dateObj.getFullYear()
    var dateObjMonth = dateObj.getMonth()
    var dateObjDate = dateObj.getDate()
    //set the previous monday value as the date given so you can modify it as needed, without taking any minutes into account
    var prevMonday = new Date(dateObjYear,dateObjMonth,dateObjDate)
    // if date of week was sunday
    if(dayOfWeek == 0){
      //substract 6 days from the date given so you get monday from the give date.
      prevMonday.setDate(dateObj.getDate() - 6);
    }else{ //substract dayOfWeek - 1 from the given date
      prevMonday.setDate(dateObj.getDate() - (dayOfWeek-1));
    }
    // return last monday's date from a given date
    return prevMonday;
}
```

this one takes a given date object and returns the previous monday from that  date object. it's an adaptation from the accepted answer as that one didnt actually work for me.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is to go back the number of days based on today's date. For example, if today's day(0) is Sunday, you can go back 6 days to find the previous Monday. If Today is Monday, you can go back 7 days. Therefore using a modulo will help you in this scenario simply because the number of days you will need to go back is %7 plus 6. 
Let me break it down in simple steps.

```
var today=new Date();
```

This will give you today's date. Now,

```
var todaysDay=today.getDay();
```

This will give you your day starting with zero.

```
var goBack=today.getDay()%7+6;
```

Now, declare a new date.

```
var lastMonday=new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-goBack);
```

Now, this will give you a numeric date value. Convert it back to Date

```
var desiredDate=new Date(lastMonday);
```

Comment: This is not correct - if today is Wednesday(3) then you would do `(3 % 7) + 6 = 9`. You do not need to go back 9 days, but instead 2 days. The correct formula is `(3 + 6) % 7 = 2`.

I.E. `goBack = (today.getDay() + 6) % 7`